# Can we prevent movie spoiler subjects from making it to the front page?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, censor

I know the particular thing I see shouldn't be a big surprise, but if I go to Stack Exchange's home page, I'd like to not be greeted with a major story point for a movie that just came out today.  Other sites such as reddit have strict moderation to keep this stuff off of their front pages.

Comment: I've recently read there are [Chrome Extensions](http://www.cnet.com/news/banish-star-wars-the-force-awakens-spoilers-with-this-chrome-extension/) available to prevent yourself from seeing any Star Wars spoilers.

Comment: Reddit? Strict moderation? Hahahahaha.

Comment: The only way to avoid seeing spoilers is being disconnected from the internet.

Comment: This is just a specific case of the problem that causes me to permanently avoid a few of our sites (mostly Arqade) unless I have a very specific reason to go there. Haven't figured out a good solution yet. For the most part, I don't know that there's much we can do other than continue to apply the Be Nice policy.

Comment: @Pops Perhaps note sites that are particularly likely to generate spoilers (e.g., Star Wars, SF) and embargo Hot Questions from "leaking" off of that site for a fixed period of time?

Answer (score 2):

You probably refer to this question currently appearing at SE home page at top

[How could an raw, untrained Force user be so adept at using the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111039/how-could-an-raw-untrained-force-user-be-so-adept-at-using-the-force)

Well, the movie is out in the wild now, and to prevent yourself getting spoilers until you've got occasion to watch it, just don't click anything containing *"Star Wars"* or *"The Force"* in the title.

What you're asking for is way off for a feature request on Stack Exchange, or applying any censorship from moderation.

The site is very different from Reddit, and that's incredibly good so.

---

If you want to prevent yourself reading/watching spoilers about Star Wars *"The Force Awakens"*, there are already [tools available](http://www.cnet.com/news/banish-star-wars-the-force-awakens-spoilers-with-this-chrome-extension/) you can use. Or just stay off the internet as it was mentioned in comments on your question.

Comment: There is a feature request to [not show questions with ignored tags on Hot Network Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271335/191265), which would also apply to the front page. If this were implemented, then in the future you could ignore a tag you want to avoid spoilers for, then not fear that it will show up on the front page. I'd encourage anyone who wants another alternative to vote for this request.

Comment: No actually you are being really thick headed about this.  The title bears the plot point.  SE is showing the title at the top of the front page. People go to this page for a lot of things, many of which are not to read plot spoilers without warning.

Comment: _"Or just stay off the internet"_ What a silly suggestion. Should I just kill myself while I'm at it?

Answer (score 2):

What counts as a "spoiler"? [For how long](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2005/12/05) (<sub><sup>warning: link goes to a comic with vulgar language)</sup></sub>? Recently on SciFi, there was [a small controversy over the title of a question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7652/what-should-the-title-of-this-harry-potter-question-be) about a minor plot point in an eight-year-old book.

These titles are also only a concern for sites that are deal with popular culture, which is not very many of them (four or five, maybe). It doesn't seem worthwhile to develop a feature targeting so small a part of the network.

On the other hand, given the grief that the HNQ list seems to cause sometimes, perhaps a generic way for moderators to remove a question from the list that they otherwise like and want to keep would be a good idea. Then each site could decide how they wanted to use that tool: if one of them decided that keeping "spoilers" off the list was important, they could do that.

Comment: My specific complaint is about HNQ, as it is *especially* likely to grab spoilers (which are likely to be topics of interest) and throw them *onto other sites*. If I visit the Star Wars SE right now, I fully expect that I may get spoilers thrown at me. I shouldn't get them on SO.

Comment: Like that supreme court judge said (approximately): I can't define pornography, but I know it when I see it.  Just because there are SOME cases which make it hard to make a one-size-fits-all rule, doesn't mean you don't address the obvious cases.

Comment: That statement is one of the worst pieces of jurisprudence the court has ever put forth.