# Don't show questions with ignored tags on Hot Network Questions

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, ignored-tags

There are some types of questions I don’t want to see, and so I [hide questions with certain tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182489/191265). However, I've found that questions with these tags can still show up in Hot Network Questions.

For example, I've ignored the tag for the latest *Star Wars* movie on Scifi/Fantasy Stack Exchange, but questions for that movie from that site show up in Hot Network Questions.

Would it be possible to make it so that Hot Network Questions does not show questions that contain tags I am ignoring on the site that the question originates from?

Comment: This is particularly relevant to spoilers in the title of Sci Fi HNQs!

Comment: This would be useful to hide all these pokemon go questions...

Comment: The Last Jedi brought me here

Comment: It would be nice to have this feature for Hot Meta Posts too. On Stack Overflow, I don't use Jobs so I have [jobs] as an ignored tag, but I still see questions about Jobs in the Hot Meta Posts.

Answer (score 8):

This is relevant again now that Endgame has hit.  Even though the posts have appropriate spoiler tags, the titles alone are giving me hints as to what occurs in the movie.  This needs to happen.

Comment: have you considered turning on [option to hide HNQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFApF.png) in user preferences?

Comment: @gnat, I might have to until I see Endgame, but I do enjoy the HNQ list overall, including for scifi and movies - it introduces me to new series, etc.  I like to collect random information about many subjects, and HNQ is a perfect tool for that, so I'd rather not turn it off,  even temporarily, if this is a simple change that the developers could make.

Comment: @SamSkuce It's a very not simple change and we have no plans to work on it any time soon.

Comment: @Catija Does that mean that this question is status-declined?

Answer (score 5):

Although the tag filtering is done [by your browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63194/505013) when viewing each page, the way it works is not very flexible, and as Catija states [in a comment above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271335/dont-show-questions-with-ignored-tags-on-hot-network-questions#comment1068630_327360) this proposal is not currently a good fit. Further to that the suggestions of completely reworking the follow/ignore process to serverside have stalled for years with [no ideal solutions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48415/505013). Certainly nothing worth overturning current functionality.

The userscript provided in [smileycreations15's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327372/176060) is a functional approach that can be customised *independently* of existing follow/ignore selections. This seems like the most appropriate solution which solves the spoiler cases, and can be adapted to suit other needs without cost to other users or the network. Existing tag tools are quite complex to tweak because they are site specific, while Hot Network Questions are network-wide, where identical tags may have a completely different meaning.

In short, tags are not easily used to identify content across the whole Stack Exchange network, so filtering Hot Network Questions with tags would not behave consistently.

Comment: Although I can see the huge undertaking in changing from client to server side, stating " Certainly nothing worth overturning current functionality. " really gets me. If you'd left that out I'd probably upvoted your answer, now it is a downvote. I feel dictated to a specific view point if I upvoted, and many small issues may make for a good reason to change behavior in the end; this argument would go for any of those changes, but does it measure up to all of them?

Comment: thankyou, i do see how tethering my value bias to the answer wasn't very popular.  the votes given are for it's current wording so it rests.  i felt that way because the question is specific to using tags, not for solving spoilers by any other means, which seems needlessly restricted.  for my purposes it is sufficient to 'zoom' the page to 1.33 so hnq reflows to end of page, am i being too literal or is that out of scope?

Answer (score 3):

This can increase a user clicking the question, and also prevent showing the user irrelevant questions.
But, developing this feature will be harder than hiding individual sites on the sidebar.
This will help prevent unwanted questions from being shown in the HNQ.
I say we should implement it.
You can write a complicated userscript, but the simplest solution is to hide the entire site with a userscript.
Here is a example (taken from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232424/460139)) (set the ignore variable to a comma-seperated list of sites to hide):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Hide SE site from Hot Questions
// @namespace   stackexchange
// @description Hide certain Stack Exchange sites from the Hot Network Questions list.
// @include     *stackoverflow.com*
// @include     *superuser.com*
// @include     *serverfault.com*
// @include     *askubuntu.com*
// @include     *stackapps.com*
// @include     *mathoverflow.com*
// @include     *.stackexchange.com*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

/*
For list of Stack Exchange sites, look here:
    http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic

Put your excluded sites here under variable 'ignore'.  Example, if you want to ignore Arqade and Mathematica:
    var ignore="Arqade,Mathematica";
*/
//This is just an example list, I have nothing against these sites, they just happened to have Hot Questions when this was made
var ignore="Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, TeX - LaTeX";

var questList=document.getElementById("hot-network-questions").getElementsByTagName("li");
var curSite="";

ignore=","+ignore.replace(/, /g, ",");

for(i=0;i<questList.length;i++){
    curSite=questList[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].title;
    if(curSite.indexOf("Stack Exchange")>1) {
        curSite=curSite.substring(0, curSite.length - 15);
    }

    if(ignore.indexOf(","+curSite)>-1) {
        questList[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```