# Is it possible and acceptable to temporarily remove specific posts from HNQ?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

I need Stack Overflow for working purposes, so I automatically see every now and then the HNQ's.

In my spare time I'm watching *[Game of Thrones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones)* and not past season 6 yet.

Since weekly the episodes of season 7 get published, the HNQ just get flooded with GoT questions every Tuesday. Even the titles that carefully are phrased not to spoil leak hints I simply would like to not have yet. Not to mention the titles that get HNQ before spoilers got removed from their titles.

For me it isn't feeling fair, having a free time activity I enjoy, getting spoiled by the fact that I have to use SO on work.

So is there anything I can do to prevent this? Or is there a way maybe even moderators could prevent this?

Comment: Do you use a browser that supports user scripts? You could try putting `document.getElementById("hot-network-questions").style.display="none";` into one.

Comment: @PeterJ yeah I am using that user script for more than a month. But slight differences are there

Comment: @PeterJ: I'll try and check it out. but for now lets assume I don't.

Comment: In case if you want to filter specific words from specific site, you can try [Jeremy Banks's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272128/) chrome extension.

Comment: Related: [Don't show questions with ignored tags on Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271335/351462)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no method that allows you to turn of it.

But you can try it with a User Script.

Since you said that you are using Stack Overflow only, I am posting a User Script that works only for Stack Overflow

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove HNQ
// @namespace    https://sagarvd01.github.io/
// @version      1
// @description  Remove the HNQ part from the Stack Exchange sites
// @author       Sagar V
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @run-at       document-end
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('#hot-network-questions').remove();
})();
```

You need a browser that support userscript and  some plugin like Tapermonkey or greasemonkey to run userscripts.

The above userscript will remove the HNQ section when the page loaded.

[image]

You can enable HNQ by disabling this userscript.

[image]

If you want to enable this in other network sites too,

add the param

```
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        https://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        https://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        https://*.askubuntu.com/*
```

add the full custom domains (with wildcards, so meta sites are included, too)

Comment: To further refine it - you can hide only HNQ from certain sites. For example: `$("#hot-network-questions a[href*='movies.stackexchange']").parent().hide()`

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/) or [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en), you can hide the Hot Network Posts section by creating a filter for `*.stackexchange.com###hot-network-questions`

[image: Blocking ###hot-network-questions]

I tried using this method to block specific questions, but unfortunately the random order of Hot Network Questions makes this impossible.