# Can we have a way to limit or otherwise control with Stack Exchange sites we see on our questions page?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

For a variety of reasons, I'd love to be able to restrict which questions I see on my Stack Exchange  questions page (i.e.: https://stackexchange.com/questions).

For instance, I haven't seen *[Avengers: Endgame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Endgame)* yet and am starting to see questions come out that, sooner or later, are going to spoil something. The same goes for [GOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones).

Additionally, I personally find the [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) questions somewhat tedious and would like to avoid them.

Is there a way to achieve this, much like we can do with tags on specific Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: What do you mean by "questions page"? By the way, note that you can ignore the [avengers-endgame](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-endgame) tag. Doesn't that work for you? At the moment there's only provision for tag-based limiting.

Comment: I think they're referring to the stackexchange.com homepage, @Blue.

Comment: You mean something [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222721/how-to-avoid-hot-network-questions-on-the-sidebar) which is already available or something [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites) which isn't yet.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog that's correct. I've updated the question accordingly. Also, thanks for the thoughtful pronoun choice. I use he/him/his.

Comment: @Blue, as far as I am aware, you cannot ignore tags from a specific exchange on the StackExchange questions page.

Comment: @Dancrumb That's true. There was a [related feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271335) too. Anyway, it should be possible to write up a userscript for ignoring site-specific tags fairly easily i.e. something similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232424/437611).

Comment: @RobertLongson those are close, but they seem to only affect the "Filtered Questions" page and not the landing page.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying. I use plural pronouns out of habit. Also, note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, on questions requesting new features, voting [is used to signify agreement or disagreement with a given proposal](/help/whats-meta), so if your question gets downvoted, it may just mean that people disagree with your proposal, not necessarily that your question is bad for the site.

Comment: I feel this poster's pain.  I've finally hidden the HNQ after seeing all the questions clamoring for rep the day after a huge show comes out.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestions in some of the comments, I'm offering this to those that could use it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Hide SE site from Hot Questions
// @namespace   stackexchange
// @description Hide certain Stack Exchange sites from the Hot Network Questions list.
// @match     https://stackexchange.com/*
// @match     https://stackexchange.com
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

/*
For list of Stack Exchange sites, look here:
    http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic

Put your excluded sites here under variable 'ignore'.  Example, if you want to ignore Arqade and Mathematica:
    var ignore="Arqade,Mathematica";
*/
//This is just an example list, I have nothing against these sites, they just happened to have Hot Questions when this was made
var ignore=["scifi.stackexchange.com", "worldbuilding.stackexchange.com"];


var questList=document.getElementById("question-list").getElementsByTagName("div");
var curSite="";
    console.info('Running...');

for(let i=0;i<questList.length;i++){
    const sid=questList[i].dataset.sid;
    if(ignore.includes(sid)) {
        questList[i].style.height = "0";
        questList[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```