# Let me opt-out of certain sites for Hot Network Questions to avoid TV spoilers posted by inconsiderate people

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, spoilers

While I was using Stack Overflow at work, someone's just spoilt the twelve-hour old *Game of Thrones* season finale for me with an extremely ill-advised question title over on SFF.SE. **Hot Network Questions** popped it up right there alongside the answer I was reading about whether C++ strictly "includes" C from a language lawyer perspective. My efforts to entirely avoid Facebook, YouTube, Quora, Twitter and SFF.SE itself throughout today were ultimately, then, in vain. The question's title has since been edited (presumably by a higher-rep user — I didn't look at anything but the page title), but it's too late.

The least invasive change I can think of proposing right now is to allow us to remove certain sites from the Hot Network Questions rotation. So if we're in the middle of *Game of Thrones* season, I'd probably remove SFF.SE and Movies & TV from my HNQ display. I do find myself visiting lots of interesting questions on those sites through HNQ, but short of making spoilers punishable by death and hoping that word of this new law spreads, I can't think of anything else to suggest.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Filter “Hot Network Questions” by excluding sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225297/300411)

Comment: Dang. Okay but it was "deferred" two years ago. Now what?

Comment: @Nathaniel not a dup. this is a very specific complaint about TV spoilers.

Comment: Possibly better dupe: [Prevent questions with movie/TV show/game spoilers from appearing in the Hot Questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224108) See also: [Can we prevent cultural movie spoiler subjects from making it to the front page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271333)

Comment: Another solution, from the other direction, would be allowing moderators to pull (spoil-y) questions on their site off of the list (for which I thought there was a FR, but can't find now). As a bonus, that would help sites deal with other problems caused by HNQ.

Comment: @JoshCaswell By the time a moderator sees this (I guess you mean a diamond moderator and not just a user with enough rep) it would probably already be too late for a lot of people.

Comment: Agree with Lisa. Such a feature wouldn't be much better than editing the title, which took place even in this situation ... but it was too late. Some people go as far as to suggest "just stay off the internet", which is rather [silly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271333/can-we-prevent-movie-spoiler-subjects-from-making-it-to-the-front-page#comment911481_271338).

Comment: Seeing that those sites you mention already have an running, enforced and working "no spoilers in titles" policy, I can't really see what problem you are actually trying to solve here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell This would require manual intervention. But if employing manual intervention anyway, then why not just fix the title *according to the existing policy of avoiding spoilers in titles*.

Comment: @ChristianRau: "Working"? I beg to differ, else I wouldn't have posted this question. Did you read it?

Comment: @ChristianRau This "spoiler-free title policy" produces some of [the most atrocious titles](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133286/14624) on the network, if not the Internet as a whole: utterly undescriptive and useless for anyone who's not already looking at the question. (Not to mention the [edit wars](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/133037/revisions) that they incite.) It's not a solution to anything.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It is, if done properly. And since it needs to be done for the courtesy of that site's community anyway, there is not reason for *another* manual method just for HNQs on top of that, since the former already covers it.

Comment: @Christian: It does not cover it.